# How to diagnose XSLT problems with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, xslt

Is there a way to see error messages / debug information on what happens when Firefox 3 applies an XSLT transformation? In Firefox I am getting only the content of the text nodes of the XML document. The stylesheet is in the same directory and is bound with `<?xml-stylesheet ...>`. In Internet Exporer it works fine and Altova XML Spy does not complain, either. I just don't know how to find out what's wrong.

Comment: do you use '<?xml-stylesheet >' or javascript ? is you stylesheet located in the same directory than your XML ? what does the JS console says ?

Comment: post your stylesheet and maybe we can help you.

Comment: I've added a clarification that I use '<?xml-stylesheet >' with a stylesheet in the same directory. So the JS-console is empty.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thank you, but I am not looking for help on the specific stylesheet - which is too large for this, anyway - but for a way to help myself when this kind of problem occurs again. "Give a man a fish, and you'll feed him for a day. Teach him how to fish, and you'll feed him for life." :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the culprit was the NoScript plugin. In case of XSLT errors you would usually get an error page as well as an entry in the error console in the extras menu. But all I got in this case is a crossed out icon in the status bar. 8-}